# background image along with background color problem

Tags: html, css

Hey Designers and Developers i have  a problem  in a  project, i want to add a background color  into background image , but not worked, i tried some methods here in community but still didnt worked,  i added snippet for this
Any solution for this ?
Thanks so much who wants to helps me

```css
.background {
  width:100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60), #651fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
  <div class="background">1</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear as to what you want. The background colour is appearing, it is just behind the image. How do you intend for this to look?

Comment: i want to make like overlay of background

Comment: your explanation leaves way to much room for interpretation. I assume you want to have a slightly transparent colored overlay in the background. which color and transparency to you intend to use?

Comment: Possibly, look into using the `filter:` property to get the look you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use a background-image and a background-color at the same time. As soon as the background-image is loaded, it will be rendered above the background color. What youc an do, is to place a pseudo-div spanning the entire width and height and use a background-color on this pesudo-div. Be sure to sue a rgba value as otherwise the background will be non-transpaerent and hide the background-image.

However, ther content will be influenced at the same time, so the content has to be pushed to the front (layer-wise) with the use of z-index (`e.g..content { z-index: 1; }`).

To span the layer with the background-color the entire width, I gave the parent the attribute: `position: relative;`.
Next I used for the layer `position: absolute;`. I gave it a `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` so it will be spanned the entire parents space.

```css
.background {
  width:100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60), #651fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="content">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this helps me so much , thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix background colours and background images like that, so here is a solution by:

a. making the colours semi-transparent

b. turning it into a linear-gradient

c. putting it **before** the image so it goes on top

```css
.background {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(#651fffaa,#651fffaa), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">1</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'am Using `background:before` for catch a Background Image.
Into Code, We will got a transparent black with white text

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  background: #000; /* Change Transparent Color */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.background h1 {
padding: 50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
color: #fff;
}

.background:before {
content: ' ';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1; /* Must z-Index 1 */
opacity: 0.6; /* Set Opacity for Background Transparent */ 
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500964757637-c85e8a162699?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <div class="background"><h1>1. I'am Only Try</h1></div>
```

Comment: opacity doenst add transparency. for transparency you have other values like transparency or integrated into RGBa. Opacity can cause a variety of other issues as it is rendered last. Means if you try to have a link or button inside the text, it wont be clickable because the opacity will prevent it.

Comment: Depending on what it's used for, if it's a click action, I still have other code. @tacoshy

Comment: but that is exactly the thing. You use the wrong tools. If somebody wants to sue links or buttons you need to fix that with more code. Simply use the right method as transparency or RGBa instead of opacity. Answers should always work not only in evry specific cases.